# Output of a c code like with call by reference

Tags: c, binding, parameter-passing

Given this C code:

```
int x=12,y=10;

void tswap(int pa, int pb) {
   int tmp;
   tmp=pa;
   pa=pb;
   pb=tmp;
   x=x+pa;
   x=x-pb;
   y++;
   printf("%d %d %d %d\n",pa,pb,x,y);
}

int main() {
    int a=4;
    tswap(x,a);
    printf("%d %d %d\n",x,y,a);
    return 0;
}
```

I have to figure out what it would print if C used call-by-reference.

Here is my expectations. 
First of all  
x=12 y=10 and a=4

```
after tswap(12,4):
pa=x=12 pb=a=4

after tmp=pa:
tmp=pa=x=12
-----------
after pa=pb:
tmp=x=12
pa=pb=a=4
-------------
after pb=tmp:
pb=tmp=x=12
pa=a=4

after x=x+pa
x=16
------------
and after x=x-pb and y++
x=4,y=11
```

So I think x=4, pb=12, pa=4, y=11; but the answer says -4 12 -4 11. Where I am wrong?

Comment: There is no call-by-reference in C.  To find out what your code does, just compile and run it.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I know that no call-by-reference in C  and also it is said on the top ."  c code like" So  ,just think a code similar syntax with c and having call-by-reference

Comment: @OliCharlesworth what would you call `int a=1, b=2; tswap(&a, &b);` with `void tswap(int* pa, int* pb){...}`  ?

Comment: @A4L i think you could not do that with a ANSI C but please focus my question.

Comment: @A4L: Pass-by-address, probably.  (I appreciate that there's no firm definition, though.)

Comment: @caesar_: So your question is "in a hypothetical language, what would this code do?"?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth +1 (in c++ this would make a difference though)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yea you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no recursion here, and all variables have distinct names, we can "cheat" a bit and change the local variables to globals (since this won't cause any name conflicts):

```
int x=12, y=10; /* original globals */
int tmp;        /* belongs to tswap */
int a;          /* belongs to main */

void tswap(int pa, int pb) {
   tmp=pa;
   pa=pb;
   pb=tmp;
   x=x+pa;
   x=x-pb;
   y++;
   printf("%d %d %d %d\n",pa,pb,x,y);
}

int main() {
    a=4;
    tswap(x,a);
    printf("%d %d %d\n",x,y,a);
    return 0;
}
```

Since `tswap` is only called once, we know that its `pa` parameter is *always* aliased to `x`, and its `pb` parameter is *always* aliased to `a`. So, we can just get rid of the parameters, replacing them with the variables that they alias:

```
int x=12, y=10;
int tmp;
int a;

void tswap() {
   tmp=x;
   x=a;
   a=tmp;
   x=x+x;
   x=x-a;
   y++;
   printf("%d %d %d %d\n",x,a,x,y);
}

int main() {
    a=4;
    tswap();
    printf("%d %d %d\n",x,y,a);
    return 0;
}
```

At this point, this is just regular C code; we no longer have any parameters, so "pass-by-reference" and "pass-by-value" are equivalent. Tracing through:

```
int x=12, y=10;
int tmp;
int a;

void tswap() {
   tmp=x;       /* x=12, y=10, tmp=12, a=4 */
   x=a;         /* x=4, y=10, tmp=12, a=4 */
   a=tmp;       /* x=4, y=10, tmp=12, a=12 */
   x=x+x;       /* x=8, y=10, tmp=12, a=12 */
   x=x-a;       /* x=-4, y=10, tmp=12, a=12 */
   y++;         /* x=-4, y=11, tmp=12, a=12 */
   printf("%d %d %d %d\n",x,a,x,y);    /* prints "-4 12 -4 11" */
}

int main() {
    a=4;        /* x=12, y=10, tmp is uninitialized, a=4 */
    tswap();    /* x=-4, y=11, tmp=12, a=4; prints "-4 12 -4 11" */
    printf("%d %d %d\n",x,y,a); /* prints "-4 11 4" */
    return 0;
}
```