# output of a function which has passByName parameter passing paradigm

Tags: c, pass-by-name

I've tried to figure out what is the output of a code like this .By the way ,It is not a real question, kind of therical question, i mean it is not an original c code, it is kind of a PL having c-code syntax and passed by name parameter paradigm.

```
int x=12,y=10;
void tswap(int pa, int pb) {
int tmp;
tmp=pa;
pa=pb;
pb=tmp;
x=x+pa;
x=x-pb;
y++;
printf("%d %d %d %d\n",pa,pb,x,y);
}

int main() {
int a=4;
tswap(x,a);
printf("%d %d %d\n",x,y,a);
tswap(++x,++y);
printf("%d %d %d\n",x,y,a);
return 0;
}
```

I think the output of first part should be :

```
-4 12 -4 11
-4 11 12
```

But i could find a logical solution for the part tswap (++x, ++y)
Is there anyone who can know how can I handle with this part ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How is this different to your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866828/output-of-a-c-code-like-with-call-by-reference

Comment: @OliCharlesworth as you can see i wonder the output of the code in case of callByName paradigm

Answer (score 1):

```
tswap(++x,++y)
```

is the same as:

```
++x;
++y;
tswap(x,y);
```

making your output:

```
4 12 4 11
4 11 4
12 5 12 13
12 13 4
```